# Testing an API by adding a new item using curl

Tags: node.js, mongodb, curl, heroku, ionic2

I'm following [this tutorial](https://blog.ionic.io/one-mean-ionic-2-todo-app-on-heroku-part-1/amp/) and I am having problems with the final part where we test the api by adding a Todo using this curl command...

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"description":"Order a tall stack of pancakes, just because."}' https://your-app-name.herokuapp.com/api/todos
```

When I enter this I am given the following error on the command line...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Bad Request</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Any helping in explaining this error would be appreciated.

Comment: try using postman instead of cURL and take care sending request as JSON.

Comment: try using `heroku logs` in order to check your application logs, then you might be able to obtain more info regarding the error

Comment: It might be that the curl command is a GET request and not a POST. Try: `curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"description":"Order a tall stack of pancakes, just because."}' https://your-app-name.herokuapp.com/api/todos`